# How to avoid TypeError when calling keyword from the "Run Keyword If" (Robot Framework)

Tags: robotframework

I have a nested dictionary inside another dictionary created in .py file.
When I am calling it like that

```
FOR    ${key}    IN    @{keys}
    I fill "${key}" tab on Applicant page with "${data}[${key}]" data
END
```

it works absolutely fine. However, if I use this call

```
Run Keyword If    $ADD_TO_BANKING_KEY in $keys    I add Applicant to Banking with "${data}[${ADD_TO_BANKING_KEY}]" data
```

I always get an error "*TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a dictionary or dictionary-like, got string instead*." when I am trying to use the argument as a dictionary inside "I add Applicant to Banking with ..." function.

Example of the "${data}[${ADD_TO_BANKING_KEY}]": {'Member No.': 'DO_NOT_CHECK', 'Benefit': 'Regular', 'Reason Opened': 'radio'}

How can I solve this issue and do it in the right way?
Thank you!

**Update**:
First function:

```
I add Applicant to Banking with "${data}" data
    Log To Console    \#\#\# I add Applicant to Banking with "${data}" data
    I fill "Add To Banking" tab on Applicant page with "${data}" data
```

Second Function:

```
I fill "${tabName}" tab on Applicant page with "${data}" data
    Log To Console    \#\#\# I fill "${tabName}" tab on Applicant page with "${data}" data
    @{keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${data}
    FOR    ${key}    IN    @{keys}
        I input "${data['${key}']}" to "${key}" element in "${tabName}" tab on "Applicants" page
    END
```

There is a place where it is failed

```
 @{keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${data}
```

Third function:

```
I input "${value}" to "${elementName}" element in "${tabName}" tab on "${pageName}" page
    [Documentation]    Input ``value`` to ``elementName`` element in ``tabName`` tab on the ``pageName`` page
    Log To Console    \#\#\# I input "${value}" to"${elementName}" element in "${tabName}" tab on "${pageName}" page
    ${tempLocator}=    Get Locator From DOM    ${RETAIL_DOM}    ${pageName}    ${elementName}    ${tabName}
    SeleniumExtendedResource.Input Value    ${tempLocator}    ${value}
```

Comment: I think you also need to show us the keyword where the type error occurs since that's seems to be where the problem lies.

Comment: I have attached the code. Why I did not do it originally because it works fine when I am calling this function without "Run Keyword If".

Comment: _${data}[${ADD_TO_BANKING_KEY}]": {'Member No.': 'DO_NOT_CHECK', 'Benefit': 'Regular', 'Reason Opened': 'radio'}_ probably this is treated as string check your ${data} variable whether is is standard robot framework dictionary of string

Comment: @Dev It is a Python dictionary. If I call "I add Applicant to Banking with" without "Run Keyword If " it is treated as a dictionary, not a string.